# PHP on dreamweaver showing up as all blue text as if error, but I cant figure out why

Tags: php

I have this piece of code that brings up a tooltip information text from my database. Its not working as it should, when I look on dreamweaver all the code is blue, where as the <?php is normally red. I've been looking at it for hours and cant see the reason, I know its probably something simple so would appreciate a fresh set of eyes on it.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="covername-i"><img data-original-title= "   <div class='covername-title-text'><?php echo $cover_arr->CoverName ; //echo $value->id; ?></div>
                                                                                                    <?php echo  $cover_arr->CoverNameText; ?>" data-placement="bottom"  class="tootltiplink" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/info-icn-wht.png" class="cover-types-info" alt="<?php echo $cover_arr->CoverName ; ?> Explanation"/></div>
```

Comment: your `<img>` tag is missing `/>` ?

Comment: It is there on the end, I've now figured why it was marked as blue, I had a duplicate class, but the tooltop is still not working, its working on the live site though, just not localhost.